# How to use JavaScript to click a div like button on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm currently trying to automate a game called Lyrics Training (https://www.lyricstraining.com/) and I am able to get the words that are from the button through some other code but I am currently struggling with clicking the "button" because it is for some reason classified as a  in the HTML code. I was wondering whether there was a way or a function that would allow me to click it so I could finish the automation? Thanks!

So far I have this code that would work if the button was an actual button:

```
let firstChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s1")[0];
    let secondChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s2")[0];
    let thirdChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s3")[0];
    let fourthChoice = document.getElementsByClassName("slot s4")[0];

    // the click function isn't working
    for(let i = 0; i < click_order.length; i++){
        let word = click_order[i];
        if(firstChoice.innerHTML === word){
            firstChoice.click();
        }else if(secondChoice.innerHTML === word){
            secondChoice.click();
        }else if(thirdChoice.innerHTML === word){
            thirdChoice.click();
        }else if(fourthChoice.innerHTML === word){
            fourthChoice.click();
        }
    }
```

This is how the "buttons" look like in the HTML code of the website:

[image: DIV Buttons]

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors and http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode to adjust your question.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not misinterpreting anything, then it sounds like you are trying to automate a game on some website. I'm not sure exactly how they coded the game, but there is a chance the code doesn't actually listen for "click" events.

It seems like your code only works if the website's code responds to click events such as:

```
div.addEventListener("click", somefunction);
//or
btn.addEventListener("click", somefunction);
```

In this case, your code would still work on divs.

However, they could be responding to mousedown events:

```
div.addEventListener("mousedown", somefunction);
```

If this is the case, you might want to read up on invoking specific events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

But please keep in mind that many websites have code preventing this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Give the button div element an attribute of role="button". This should work fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response!

I tried what you said but the function still does not work.

This is the current code, please tell me if I implemented your suggestion incorrectly, thank you!
`                  
 // add role="button" to all choices
                    firstChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    secondChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    thirdChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
                    fourthChoice.setAttribute("role", "button");
`